# Как найти если символ в строке python

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная "buy" в которую пользователь вписывает цифру или символ и программа проверяет есть ли этот символ в строке "weap" как такое можно провернуть как можно легче ? Я уже делал такую программу но код был слишком большим .

Comment: `if symbol in string:`, ну то есть в вашем случае `if buy in weap:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if buy in weap:
    # код
```

Или

```
weap.find(buy)
# возвращает номер символа в строке или если его нет, то -1
```

Comment: Это, скорее, комментарий  по практике сайта.

Answer (score -1):

Python string method **find()** determines if string str occurs in string, or in a substring of string if starting index beg and ending index end are given.

[см. здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)

Comment: `find` избыточен, если конкретная позиция не нужна, для проверки факта наличия достаточно `in`